# Which are the architectures to support today?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm developing an android app using

> opencv library version 330.

The current size of the compiled project is about 100 MB!
Is really too big.
Using proguard for the app module, APK size is reduced by about 3 or 4 MB.
Using Proguard on the opencv library I get an error. I have not been able to find the solution yet I've been using proguard for a long time...

I imported the library by creating the jniLibs folder under `app/sr/main`.
Now this folder contains 7 more folders!

- arm64-v8
- armeabi
- armeabi-V7A
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86-64

Each of the above listed folders contains the respective .so file...

I noticed that removing some of these folders the size of the apk is drastically reduced.
I'm not an architecture's expert, but I could remove armeabi folders since (from what I understand), there's no need to support that kind of architecture.

Since my app is almost ready for release, for android devices, would I know if anyone can tell me what are the architectures to support ?????

Thank you, guys :D

> [This is what i'm including](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeje.png)

Comment: Have a read of: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html - there used to be a %age breakdown of devices ... still looking for that

Comment: Are you including `opencv_world.so` file?

Comment: I'm not including opencv_world.so.... i' m including that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeje.png

Comment: You may safely remove the `mips` and `mips64` arch devices, I rarely see these arch devices as of now. `armv8` is the latest among all of them. And is generally required on high-end phones.

Comment: I would like to try out an experiment here, I have seen some projects running on a single `.so` file, so I mean that these architectures are cross compatible, with just some performance degradation. However I am not sure how that works, maybe some tweaks in gradle file are required.

Comment: I tried to delete mips and mips64 but the project is not compiled.
The problem is that 100 MB for a .apk are really too many! I just have to trust in Gradle. I think I'll open another post where I'll ask what are the reasons for the error being compiled when minifyEnable is true! However, I thank everyone for the constant help! you are great! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to build multiple apk for each architecture by splitting it up then you can upload it one by one to the Play Store. Read more at 
[Build Multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html)

You can do it by adding the [`split`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.Splits.html) block in your app build.gradle:

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

      // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
      enable true

      // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
      // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

      // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
      reset()

      // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

      // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So wich ABIs i must compile for app release? thanks for the help:)

Comment: you can compile the app for each architecture so your application will cover large user base. The only downside is you need to upload each of them to google play store.